# Advection Fog or____________

Tags: meteorology

If there is snow on the ground in the fall season, at a location 50 km away north of a warmer body of water to the south  and that location is receiving fog, what is causing the fog that is occurring in the morning despite very little wind and not from a southerly direction.

Comment: You need to provide more information about this place and whereabouts it is in the world. Britain, for example, is close to the Gulf Stream and the prevailing wind is S. westerly, so that explains many British fogs.

Comment: Sorry, my intention was a large continent but a location close to a large body of water such as a lake. Thank you for your clarification question.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question and related it to a specific place, then we could evaluate the exact circumstances.

Comment: I agree. But would one normally associate the Britain with snow on the ground in fall? That is a question in itself.

Comment: The first snow in southern Britain usually comes in November, but with climate warming over the last 50 years, it rarely settles. On the Welsh and Scottish hills, settled snow is more common in the fall.

Comment: That sounds very similar to Southern Ontario but geographically, we are positioned at a much lower latitude of 43-44 degrees north vs 10 degrees higher approximately for that part of Britain. This year, snow was on the ground through much of November due to earlier and longer advances of Polar air masses, yet north of my home where I work, fog was a very regular occurrence in the morning with snow on the ground and lack of southern flow of warm air.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102212/discussion-between-j-kaciulis-and-michael-walsby).